# ios drawing on screen

Tags: ios, swift

So, as a swift novice, I'm noodling around and learning as I go. Generally a little google foo or a tutorial will help me, but now I'm stumped. So if anyone could explain this to me I would be very happy.
So I'm trying to draw a circle on screen, well, a few of them actually. I found this code online;

(http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/drawing-circles-uitouch-ios8-swift)

```
import UIKit
class CircleView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        //... various stuff to draw a circle ..//
    }
}
```

it's a class that draws a circle when initialised like this

```
currentCircle = CircleView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100 ) )
```

I have a few questions though.

Why does it actually draw a circle? the drawRect function never gets called directly. I guess it's because we're overriding a function in UIView, and I don't understand those concepts yet.

How can a pass variables to the initialisation of that function? Say, I want to draw circles of different thickness and I want to pass an extra variable like so:

```
currentCircle = CircleView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100 ), thickness:10  )
```

How would I modify the init to accept this? adding it like this:

```
override init(frame: CGRec, thickness: Int) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

triggers an error (initialiser does override a designated initialiser from its superclass)

And why all the overrides? I've tried making it a class and using the code to draw. However,

```
CGContextAddArc
```

triggers a compiler error saying the context isn't valid, so I suppose

```
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
```

isn't returning anything useful.

or if anyone knows a useful resource where I can learn a bit more about overriding and initialising classes, that would be welcome.

Comment: `drawRect:` is documented. Read the doc. It's called, and if you don't overwrite it, it won't do anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (im  sorry but) I dont think SO is a site to learn about basic programming topics.

this too broad and not a good fit for a QA-style page

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it actually draw a circle?

You're correct that you never directly call `drawRect:`. It's called by the system when the view needs to be redrawn. This happens when, for example, the bounds of the view change, or you call `setNeedsDisplay()`

> How would I modify the init…

Your init should look like this:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRec, thickness: Int) {
    self.thickness = thickness
    self.init(frame: frame)
}
```

You can only override methods from your class's superclasses, `init(frame: CGRec, thickness: Int)` isn't one of them.

You should take time to read [Apple's Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/) before embarking on tutorials. All you need to know about the language is in there.

For more info on drawing, see Defining a Custom View, [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23)

Answer (score 0):

An elegant approach is to turn your view into a class with full Interface Builder support. That way you can directly add and configure instances of your view in Interface Builder.

To use your custom view:

- Select and insert a view
- In the *Identity Inspector* view, set the *Custom Class* property to your class name (CircleView)
- In the *Attributes Inspector* view, set the thickness

There are slightly modifications to your code needed, in particular the annotations `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CircleView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var thickness: CGFloat = 1

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, thickness)
        var r = self.bounds
        var ellipseRect = CGRectMake(r.origin.x + self.thickness / 2, r.origin.y + self.thickness / 2,
            r.size.width - thickness, r.size.height - thickness)
        CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, ellipseRect)
    }
}
```

And yes, you're right. You never call 'drawRect:' yourself. You add instances of your view to your screens and iOS will call 'drawRect:' when it needs to paint your view.

It's the overall patterns of an graphical user interfaces system: you mainly react to events such as clicks from the user or repaint events.